# Where clause that includes IN and NOT IN

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT professor.pr_name, professor.pr_college, professor.pr_salary
FROM professor
WHERE professor.pr_salary NOT IN ('Education') > professor.pr_salary IN ('Education')
ORDER BY professor.pr_salary DESC;
```

I have to make it so that it lists the names of all the professors not in the college of education that earn more than the professors in the college of education. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by `WHERE professor.pr_salary NOT IN ('Education') > professor.pr_salary IN ('Education')` ?? if you replace the > with & it should work. why the bigger than here? it's out of context

Comment: Please share your table(s) structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample.

Comment: It needs to be greater than because I need to show the pr_salary only of the professors NOT in the college of education that MAKE MORE than the pofessors in the college of education.

Comment: Are you planning to do ANY of your homework yourself? What is this, your fourth problem in your homework set you posted in the last few hours?

Comment: @Deniz 1)what values does the pr_salary column contain?

Comment: @Deniz 2) Is `Education` a name of college?

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be asking lots of questions about your assignment, I am not going to present a complete solution - you will need to put that together.

You can find the salaries of the professors in education like this:

```
SELECT pr_salary
FROM   professor
WHERE  pr_college = 'Education'
```

*(It is not clear which column the `'Education'` value should reference as it is not a salary - you should update this as appropriate - or if it is not in the `PROFESSOR` table then you ought to update the question with your table definitions.)*

You can then use the `MAX()` aggregation function to find the highest salary of those values.

Similarly, you can find the details of professors not in education like this:

```
SELECT pr_name,
       pr_college,
       pr_salary
FROM   professor
WHERE  pr_college <> 'Education'
ORDER BY pr_salary DESC;
```

Then you need to add in another filter condition to test if the salaries out of education are higher than the maximum in education using a correlated sub-query:

```
WHERE  ...
AND    pr_salary > ( /* Previous maximum value */ )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT professor.pr_name from professor where pr_college<>'Education'and professor.pr_salary >(select max(pr_salary) from professor where pr_college='Education' group by pr_college);
```